# Linking multiple Trie objects

Tags: c#, .net, list, grouping, trie

I currently have a task to take Options Symbols and make them easily searchable from a cache for fast lookups from various different applications both web and windows based.  We have settled on making a WFC service to return the results for us.
There are approx 500k records that are needed to cache.  When we do this our memory footprint is approximately 400 MB using a Trie Object. I was instructed to make that smaller.

An option symbol looks like this in our world `ROOT:DATESTRING:PRICE:TYPE` or `IBM:130119:215.0:C`

So I was thinking that since there is tons of duplication in this I could build a Trie for each part which when finished made the memory usage approx 30 MB.

So my dilemma now is how to link them so it still appears as one continuous Trie for searching.  If I do a simple parent child I can end up with false results since the parent of the Price is Date and that could have prices that do not occur for that ROOT or Type.  Our current approach is to use another object that is a linking object similar to a join table in a database.  We have each final node with an UniqueID and then build the appropriate relationship.  This is still very fast and does not take huge amounts of memory but I was wondering what others may suggest as a way to link these items in a more efficient manner.

Additional Info:
So each part of the option symbol in my current implementation is its own individual Trie.
So if I have Options that are:
IBM:130119:215.0:C
APPL:130119:215.0:C
APPL:130119:600.0:C
A:130119:31:0:C
IBM:130119:220.0:C
IBM:130119:215.0:P
I would subsequently build a trie for the root like:  There is an end value as part of my node structure to know where I have hit an end.

```
    root          Date                  Price                OptType
   /   \            |                   /   \   \             / \
   A    I           1                  2      3  6           P   C
  / \   |           |                 / \     |  |
     A  B           3                2   1    1  0
     |  |           |                |   |    |  |
     P  M           0                0   5    .  0
     |              |                |   |    |  |
     L              1                .   .    0  .
                    |                |   |    |  |
                    1                0   0    0  0 
                    |
                    9
```

So without a way to link each of these I could get many false positives by just using Parent Child.  Since the Child of Date is Price.
I had thought about putting all the parent child pieces on the Root, making that a special type of NODE so as to not have a bunch of null data out there for others that are not needed.  but we settled on a linking table, however that is not working well at all.  I am not set that this is the right implementation, but we do need to CACHE all of these records due to the number of calls and frequency of them.

Comment: Are the records treated as strings or as a tuples of several objects?

Comment: Are you storing your data in Sql Server? Using Full Text Search is really fast and can handle 500k records. No need for caching or implementing your own search algorithm.

Comment: Can you give more details about the trie implementation?

Comment: @Christoffer - added more information, let me know if it is still not clear.  Not always the best at explaining.

Comment: @Wouter de Kort - Unfortunately this is for a trading system that will be used on client machines for lookups.  The speed of the lookup to the database tends to return in about .5 secs, where as this current lookup trie will return the same result in .0004 secs.

Comment: 400 Mb still sounds like a lot for a trie that small (500k strings of length ~20), I suspect you could gain at least some space by reviewing the implementation. Are you able to disclose more of the code that builds the trie?

Comment: Oh, and another relevant question: Do you need to cache database lookups on the client side or the server side? Do you cache the whole set "up front" or do you cache dynamically?

Comment: The data is stored on a server lookup that is shared by multiple applications.  Still trying to come up with a solution for this.  had to take a break for a bit.  Ultimately the size will be considerably less if I can figure out how to link.  All of the data broken out is only 125 mb.  If I don't break it out it is 400+ mb